# Sprite Kit : Most efficient way to load a big map (like Limbo/Mario)

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I am discovering Sprite Kit and Objective-C and I am wondering what is the most efficient way to load a big 2D map from the hard drive ?
Should I load the whole map at the beginning ? Should I load the position of the elements on a table and display them when they need to be displayed ? Or is there an other method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a Tile Map for that. It's much faster than loading and drawing the entire map. [This tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/62049/sprite-kit-tutorial-make-platform-game-like-super-mario-brothers-part-1) explains how to do that. (Scroll down to "Loading the TMXTiledMap".)

Comment: Thank you ! Do you know if this is the same thing than what Apple is using in Adventure ? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/

Comment: Not exactly, in that apple guide you aren't using a tmx file.

Comment: Depending on the kind of game your making I suggest combining both tmx mapping and SKPhysicsBodies. For example, in a project of mine I use tmx mapping for environment collisions (ground, rocks hills, etc), and I use Sprite Kit's physics engine for player and enemy contact.